# I am trying to print out the lower right triangle of a 2D array

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to print out the lower right triangle of a 2D array, but I get the element triangle reversed:

```
int[][] a3 = {
            {1,2,3,4},
            {5,6,7,8},
            {9,10,11,12},
            {13,14,15,16},
    };
    System.out.println("Lower right triangle");
    for (int row = 0 ; row < a3.length ; row++){
        for (int col = 3 ; col >= a3[0].length-row-1 ; col--) {

            System.out.print("\t" + a3[row][col]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

The output looks like this:

```
4
8   7
12  11  10
16  15  14  13
```

Instead of:

```
             4
          7  8
      10 11 12
   13 14 15 16
```

Comment: How have you tried to fix it?

Comment: How have you tried to fix it?

Comment: The reason it shows the way it does above is because you likely aren't having it print out with spaces, and are starting from [0][0] rather than [][array[0].length-1]

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution for you.. Try to understand the logic and ask if any doubt. hope it helps you

```
for (int row = 0 ; row < a3.length ; row++){
    for (int col = 0 ; col < a3[0].length ; col++) {
          if(col>=a3[0].length-1-row){
              System.out.print(a3[row][col]+"\t");

          } else {
              System.out.print("\t");
          }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Do you really think it helps the guy to give him the answer to his homework?

Comment: I hope he could understand the logic and clear the doubt here

Comment: logic is self explanatory

Answer (score 0):

```
int[][] a3 = {
        {1,2,3,4},
        {5,6,7,8},
        {9,10,11,12},
        {13,14,15,16},
};
System.out.println("Lower right triangle");
for (int row = 0 ; row < a3.length ; row++){
    for (int col = 0 ; col <= a3[row].length-1 ; col++) {
        if(col < a3[row].length-row-1){
            System.out.print("\t");
        }else{
            System.out.print("\t" + a3[row][col]);
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

output:

```
Lower right triangle
          4
       7  8
   10 11 12
13 14 15 16
```

Answer (score 0):

Without giving you the complete answer, consider the following... In your solution you're working right to left. In order to best attack this problem you should print left to right (which is the order of traversal). In order to do that, you need to likewise leverage your row and column index to determine the print order:

```
            if(((a3[0].length - 1) - row) <= col) {
                System.out.print(a3[row][col] + "\t");
            } else {
                System.out.print("\t");
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to print. You keep a flag to check if you have indented the very first number printed for a row. This indentation will depend upon the column you start printing from. Then, subsequently, all numbers printed will append a single indent after them.

The number of times the initial indentation happens is based on `col`, which is being calculated as  `a3[0].length - row - 1`.

```
for (int row = 0; row < a3.length; row++) {
            boolean formatted = false;
            for (int col = a3[0].length - row - 1; col <= 3; col++) {

                if (!formatted) {
                    for (int i = 0; i <= col; i++) {
                        System.out.print("\t");
                        formatted = true;
                    }
                }
                System.out.print(a3[row][col] + (col < 3?"\t":""));
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
            4
        7   8
    10  11  12
13  14  15  16
```

To visually see how the indents are applied, use a `X` in place of `\t`. This is the output. Hope this helps in understanding how initial indentation is being applied, and then the subsequent ones.

```
XXXX4
XXX7X8
XX10X11X12
X13X14X15X16
```